# Access 2007 Male, Female, Unisex Categories for either Gender

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm fairly new to Access 2007. I'm an ERP functional consultant with programming experience close to none.

I'm setting up an Access database for personal use. Let's say I have product categories as Male, Female, Unisex. I have product colors as black and white. When entering an order, I select a color (combo box) i.e black and then gender (combo box) i.e male. In the order form gender can be either male or female but not unisex.

In prodcut id field (combo box) I need to see black items with male and unisex gender.

When I set up the query in product id combo, the OR operator precedes the AND operator, then I see white items too. As a result I see all the male and unisex items.

I couldn't find a way put an OR operator within an AND operator so to speak.

I changed my approach and instead of placing Male, Female, Unisex in one field, I created two checkbox fields, Male and Female. This time I tried to query Products.Male=True if GenderCombo=Male, Products.Female=True if GenderCombo=Female along with color but no luck.

Which approach do you recommend and what should be the query like.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Bekir.

Comment: Why all the down votes? It is not a great question, but it is better than some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your query script, and note that AND has a higher precedence than OR. You will have to use brackets to get exactly what you want.

example:

```
where productcolor = 'Black' and gender = 'Unisex' or gender = 'Male'
```

this will give you all Black Unisex together with all Male of any color.

What you want is probably:

```
where productcolor = 'Black' and (gender = 'Unisex' or gender = 'Male')
```

You could also write that as:

```
where productcolor = 'Black' and gender in ('Unisex', 'Male')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I tried what you said, using inner brackets earlier. Somehow it didn't work. I deleted the field and recreated it and tried again and it worked now. Maybe I omitted something then. A rest may be useful sometimes :) Thanks again.